# Angular - *ngComponentOutlet - destroy Component

Tags: angular

I use a `*ngComponentOutlet` structural directive in order to display a dynamic component. This dynamic component must be displayed based on **some conditions**.

For example, if a certain route is matched, the component (a search form) should be displayed. Else, it should not be displayed.

I've used the following code:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="searchComponent">
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="searchComponent"></ng-container>
 </ng-container>
```

where:

```
import {SearchComponent} from '....';

public searchComponent: Type<any> | null; 
...

show(): void {
  this.searchComponent = SearchComponent;
}
 
hide(): void {
  this.searchComponent = null;
}
```

This works, but using the code above, when hiding the component, the `ngOnDestroy()` from `SearchComponent` is never called.

In Angular Documentation (https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet), I've found that:

> NgComponentOutlet requires a component type, if a falsy value is set
> the view will clear and any existing component will get destroyed.

So, I've tried to use a boolean, like this:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="shouldShow && searchComponent"></ng-container>
```

and

import {SearchComponent} from '....';

```
public searchComponent: Type<any> = SearchComponent; 
...

show(): void {
  this.shouldShow = true;
}
 
hide(): void {
  this.shouldShow = false;
}
```

This works fine for a Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m4w2tk. But using the code above in my project generates a compiler error:

`Type 'false | Type<any>' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'`

I need a clean way to remove this component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m4w2tk

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

You could also set the component ref to null:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tcbdsh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component"></ng-container>
```

Component:

```
public component = HelloWorld;

toggleHelloWorld(): void {
  if (!this.component) {
    this.component = HelloWorld;
  } else {
    this.component = null;
  }
}
```

**Option 2**

You can wrap your container in another  element and use an *ngIf on it like here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ct8xmh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
<ng-container *ngIf="show">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

This looks very much like the code you tried but the component does indeed run the OnDestroy lifecycle hook.